# How can I remove Norton?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, cleaning, norton-antivirus

Norton came pre-installed on my Win10  laptop. I used [`NRnR.exe`](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v60392881) to remove it, but still get the following at start-up:

[image]

How can I remove Norton?

---

After running [`NRnR.exe`](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v60392881) to remove it, and rebooting, Norton doesn't  show up in "programs and features":

[image]

Comment: Contact Norton Support for the proper removal tool.

Comment: @John Norton FAQ https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v60392881 points to NRnR.exe

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe contact the computer manufacturer to see if they can help

Comment: Also, if just the Startup is there (otherwise gone) try SysInternals Autorurns to remove all traces of the Norton Startup.

Comment: What Norton tool exactly did you have installed?

Comment: @Ramhound nothing, it came preinstalled

Comment: There was a version or edition associated with whatever Norton product that was installed. So provide that information.

Comment: @Ramhound I removed it: I can't that info anymore.

Comment: What is the process running that shows that window? Where is the process located and can you use that to determine the software and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Task Manager:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Remove `FSDUI_Custom.exe`.

In `CCleaner:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy. First make sure that Norton is deactivated if you can. Then go to "programs and features" and look for it. Then click to uninstall.After uninstalling it reboot your computer and then once you've logged in again, make sure to check your program files and if you see a Norton folder delete it. Some AV's are worse and leave traces all over the place so you'd end up having to also delete any additional folders in the temp files and AppData folders.

Answer (score -1):

Geek uninstaller (https://geekuninstaller.com/) uninstalls and gives you the option to clean up any registry entries as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).